# applying another css class to an element

Tags: html, css

I have the following in a stylesheet:

```
.tab {
    background-color: #1A1A1A; 
    color: #A17749; 
    font-family: Verdana,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    float: right;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.tab .select {
    height: 55px;    
}
```

Then I have a html file with:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="tab select"><a href="#">Pricing</a></div>
...
```

but somehow the css class select is not being applied. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.tab .select {` needs to be `.tab.select {`

```
.tab .select { //<- applies to tag with .select class which is child of tag with .tab class

.tab.select  { //<- applies to tag with classes .tab and .select
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector says "A member of the select class that is a *descendent* of a member of the tab class".

To say "A member of the select class that is also a member of the tab class" remove the space.

```
.select.tab {
```

Note that [this will not work properly in IE6](http://paulirish.com/2008/the-two-css-selector-bugs-in-ie6/).

Answer (score 0):

A space between selectors means that you want to apply the later rule to all descendants of the first selector.

Remove the space and it will work:

```
.tab .select {
    height: 55px;    
}
```

Your selector would have worked if your markup was:

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="tab">
          <div class="select">
             <a href="#">Pricing</a></div>
```